# Angular file input changes only shows in the first component

Tags: javascript, angular, components, progressive-web-apps

I have an image component formed from two input types :
1- text input
2- file input

> image.html

```
<div>
 <mat-card>
    <mat-card-content>
        <label for="cam">Take picture</label>
        <input id="cam" style="display: none;" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" (change)="onSelectFile($event)" /> <br>OR<br>
        <label for="gallery">Open gallery</label>
        <input id="gallery" style="display: none;" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple (change)="onSelectFile($event)" />
    </mat-card-content>

    <img *ngFor="let image of imagesList" [src]="imagesMap.get(image)" mat-card-avatar (click)="deleteImage(image)"> <br/>
    <br>

    <mat-card-header *ngIf="imagesList.length > 0">
        <mat-card-subtitle>Click on image to remove it</mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
</mat-card>

<input type="text"   placeholder="Ex. pat@example.com">
```

> image.ts

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-image',
  templateUrl: './image.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./image.component.css']
})
export class ImageComponent implements OnInit {
  files!: File[];

  imagesMap: Map<string, string> = new Map<string, string>();
  imagesList: string[] = new Array<string>();
  url = "";
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSelectFile(event: any) {
    this.files = event.target.files;
    if (this.files && this.files.length > 0) {

      for (let file of this.files) {
        if (!this.imagesMap.has(file.name)) {

          let url: string = "";
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);

          reader.onload = (event) => {
            //@ts-ignore
            url = event.target.result;
            this.imagesMap.set(file.name, url);
            this.imagesList.push(file.name);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  deleteImage(imageName: string) {
    let indexToRemove = this.imagesList.indexOf(imageName);
    if (indexToRemove != -1) {
      this.imagesList.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
      this.imagesMap.delete(imageName);
      indexToRemove = this.files.findIndex(file => file.name == imageName);
      if (indexToRemove != -1)
        this.files.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I call this component several times or duplicate it from app components ,

> app.component.html

```
<app-image></app-image>
<app-image></app-image>
```

the image that had been selected from the second or third … component , it always shows in the first one instead, this problem is with inputs of type **File** , inputs with type text are working fine . Kindly refer to the image below for a clearer view.

[Component screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbX3k.jpg)

I want to when I  add pictures in the second component (same component but duplicated) , they must shows in the second component . Each duplicated component must be independent from others.

Please can help me to solve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of duplicate Id. You have two input with Id of cam and gallery so when you click on second, one browser finds the first element and opens file chooser. It means you basically clicked on first element. don't use this approach, just simply use a [template variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables)

```
 <label (click)="file.click()">Open gallery</label>
 <input #file style="display: none;" type="file"
             accept="image/*" multiple (change)="onSelectFile($event)"/>
```